# Terraform 'tags' (plural) are deprecated - how to create multiple 'tag' entries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

So - for ASG's (auto scaling groups) code in Terraform,  newest AWS provider deprecates usage of 'tags' (plural) and asks to use a single 'tag' entry.
So if you need mulitple tags, you need multiple individual 'tag' entries .
With my current code, i get the error that looks like :

```
│ Warning: Argument is deprecated
│ 
│   with module.service.module.compute.module.controller.aws_autoscaling_group.controller,
│   on .terraform/modules/service/compute/controller/ec2.tf line 74, in resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "controller":
│   74:   tags = [for key, value in merge(local.asg_tags, var.compute_tags) :
│   75:     { key = key, value = value, propagate_at_launch = true }
│   76:   ]
│ 
│ Use tag instead
```

For some resources i can create several static 'tag' options like

```
tag {
key = 1
}
tag {
name = 2 
}
```

But how can i create some form of flat map or something, if my current code is using 'for' loops to create tags ???

```
│   74:   tags = [for key, value in merge(local.asg_tags, var.compute_tags) :
│   75:     { key = key, value = value, propagate_at_launch = true }
│   76:   ]
```

I believe its pretty new feature as can't find anything useful what is the best practise to get it sorted.
Has anyone came across that ?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used it, but maybe you can can make use of a [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks).
Based on what I see in the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group) I think it would look something like:

```
dynamic "tag" {
  for_each = tags  # your array
  content {
    key = each.key
    value = each.value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Chai for the hint, managed to create dynamic block for tags :
[image]

Works as expected !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).